# Como multiplicar datos de dos listas en C#

Tags: c#

Deseo obtener el superficie de n triángulos, en un textbox solicito la base, ya que son varias medidas de bases, paso los datos del textbox a un listbox, lo mismo he realizado para la altura. El problema es que ya tengo los datos en las listas pero no sé como multiplicar los datos almacenados en la lista_base (list_b) y lista_altura (list_h) y el producto dividirlo en 2, y mostrar la información en la lista_superficie (list_tri).

```
        int cant_tri, n, Indice;
        double h, b, superficie;
        
        cant_tri = 0;
        n= int.Parse(txt_n.Text);
        for (Indice = 0; Indice <= n - 1; Indice++)
        {
            //Se supone que aquí multiplico el dato1 de la lista_b x el dato1 de la lista_h
            b = list_b.Items.IndexOf(Indice);
            h = list_h.Items.IndexOf(Indice);
            superficie = (b * h) / 2;
            list_tri.Items.Add(superficie);
            
            
        }
```

Es el primer lenguaje que estoy aprendiendo, así que no sé que hacer para poder obtener los datos de las listas y multiplicarlos

Comment: IndexOf, como bien dice la [documentacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-6.0), devuelve el indice de un item. Si vos queres el item que esta en el indice, deberias usar la lista como si fuera un array, ya que asi se acceden a sus items.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a un grupo de discord pude, resolverlo. Si alguien tuvo la misma duda que yo aquí les dejo el código:

```
int cant_tri, n, Indice;
double h, b, superficie;
    
cant_tri = 0;
n= int.Parse(txt_n.Text);
for (Indice = 0; Indice <= n - 1; Indice++)
{
    //Se convierte la lista a double
    b = double.Parse(list_b.Items[Indice] as string);
    h = double.Parse(list_h.Items[Indice] as string);
    superficie = (b * h) / 2;
    list_tri.Items.Add(superficie);
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explicar brevemente el funcionamiento del código. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código, y sin explicación, tu pregunta y respuesta podrían no ser de utilidad para otras personas con el mismo problema más adelante. Lee [answer]. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: No se que te dijeron en discord.. pero esto se parece mucho a lo que te puse en mi comentario.. no? ;)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).